# How do you store zero in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, checkbox

This seems like it should be an easy one, but I've searched and can't seem to figure it out.  I'm using PHP to update a MySQL database which sets a few fields as boolean switches.  The trigger on the site is a checkbox.  When the user checks the box, the value is set to 1, when unchecked, the value is zero.  The problem is, when I send the form, the database updates fine when the checkbox is set, however it will not update the value of the field to zero, it simply ignores it.  I've echoed out the value when not set to verify that the variable is indeed set to zero.  I find similar problems when I try to clear a textbox and send nothing.  MySQL simply ignores it and will not clear the field.  Am I missing something?

Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {   
    if (isset($_POST['box1'])) {
        $box1 = $_POST['box1'];
    }
    else {
        $box1 = 0;
    }
    $query = "UPDATE table SET box1 = '{$box1}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}
    ?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box1"> Box 1
</form>
```

Comment: What's the result of `echo $query;`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a `WHERE` either?

Comment: Where's the `value` attribute on your checkbox?

Comment: Do not use a query like this in production code, it's horribly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The attacker could set the parameter `box1` to anything they please, which would then be thrown into the query.

Comment: Also, I think the values are set to `on` and ` ` (empty)

Comment: @gustyaquino The values are `on` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: What type is the box1 column?

Comment: @njk the result of the echo is either 1 or 0 (sorry I forgot to include value="1" in the original checkbox code.  Also in the real situation I would indeed add a WHERE clause but this was just quick and dirty to explain my problem.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="box1" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="1" />    <input type='submit'/>

Comment: If you only have a checkbox on the form and left it unchecked then may it be that $_POST is unset.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - For some reason the site didn't include my HTML form, I had it copied in the original question.  The type is <input type="checkbox" value="1">

Comment: @kitsune - I agree and normally wouldn't code it that way, however since the field is set to TINYINT, even if they managed to inject, wouldn't the end result be converted to either a 1 or 0?  Also in the full code I would of course use mysqli_real_escape_string when setting the variable.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm also having this problem when clearing out a textbox and sending a blank field.  I thought it had to do with the way MYSQL was handling NULL or zero values but based on all your comments, you all seem to feel it's based in PHP and has to do with the way I'm coding the results.  That's helpful and at least I can focus on that side of things.

Comment: @user1592417 Can you please add `or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` after your `mysqli_query` and run?

Comment: tried it with the or die and the result is the same.  I kind of expected it wasn't a problem with the query since I can sub the 0 for a 2 and it works.  I still think it's in MySQL, but I'm stumped for the moment.

Comment: @user1592417 No, they could set the POST to something along the lines of `'; DROP TABLE table; --`, which would result in the table `table` being dropped. Or, they could override any/all values. Nasty stuff. I'd also recommend against `mysqli_real_escape_string` since it's more cumbersome and error prone than just relying on parameterized queries to protect your database from your data.

Comment: @kitsune  Thanks for the tips I'll keep those in mind.  This entire conversation has got me thinking a bit about how this all works and it seems to me that rather than trying to set box=1, box=0, simply checking for the checked state of the object should be enough to logically determine the value.  This way we could use a SQL statement to set the value but not be tied to that value being supplied by the user (or by a page element).  This (at least to me) seems to be the most secure.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input so far.  I still have no idea (and I don't think anyone has addressed the fact that) I can get this entire thing to work just fine if I simply set box=1 when the box is checked and box=2 when it's not and the code operates flawlessly.  It's when I set the value to zero that MySQL just decides to ignore it and not update the field.  For this reason I still think the problem is on the MySQL side of the fence.  Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" name="box1">`

Should be

`<input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="1">`

The data type for `box1` in your database should be `INT` so even if its not set to `0` it will still be saved with a `0` because you simply can't store nothing in a field with `INT` as a data type.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP states that his checkbox carries a value of 1. His logic declares `0` for an empty box.

Comment: I'm providing an answer that works. OP said: When the user checks the box, the value is set to 1, when unchecked, the value is zero

Comment: Did you miss the comment from OP above? `sorry I forgot to include value="1" in the original checkbox code`

Comment: That's great. If the column is `INT` setting the value with nothing or null will default to `0`. All I'm saying is that it doesn't have to be set to `0`.. unless it's not an `INT`.

Comment: I have, and I also fault checked it by setting zero to 2 and using the value 2 to indicate an off state, this works fine so I'm back to thinking it's in the way MYSQL deals with zeros?

Comment: @njk Dunno if you saw on the above comments, I did try the or die and it had no effect.

Comment: Yeah error reporting is on, nothing thrown.  The code works fine, the database is being updated as expected so AFAIK the code itself is solid.  The problem is when I try to use a 0 to express OFF, the database does not get updated.  When I use a 2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, if no value is passed inside the array then no action occurs.

Consider the following...

```
...
$box1=0;

if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST['box1'])) {
        $box1 = $_POST['box1'];
    }
}
    $query = "UPDATE boxtest SET box1 = $box1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    ?>

<form method="post" action=""/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="1"/> Box 1
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

or (as per my previous comment)

```
<input type="hidden" name="box1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="1"/>
```